# Singing and transposing in the same key

Tags: voice, transposition

Hey guys I have a question. If I'm singing a song and it was too high for me by a few semi tones and I decided to sing it lower, would I have to also transpose the background music in order for it to sound right? The reason I'm asking this is because I've recently started getting into karaoke but still am quiet new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course! You'd have to transpose the whole thing to the key that is comfortable to you, otherwise it would be in two different keys at the same time!

Also, if you didn't transpose the rest of the song, it would be more difficult to sing, because you wouldn't be able to hear the harmonies that accompany the singing.

Comment: what if I'm still singing in the same key just a semitone or two lower? Do I still have to transpose the back ground track?Does that make sense?

Comment: @skyfox009 If you transpose the melody a semitone or two lower, it won't  be in the same key. It will be in a key one or two semitones lower

Comment: You are right, I just realized lol.... Just a while back, I read something on reddit that confused me. This really sucks as someone who loves karaoke but doesn't have a high voice. These apps that transpose music distort it. Do you have any advice for a newbie?

Comment: @skyfox009 Did you try to transpose the singing by a whole octave? That way you could keep the karaoke background.

Comment: As an accompanist for talent contest shows, I've known singers who have learned a song by singing along with the record perform it in THAT key, regardless of what's being played.  Physical memory rather than listening.

Comment: @ arsak many songs don't work when you go down an octave, especially if I'm trying to sing a song made for a male tenor.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - true, I've tried accompanying such. Perfect *memory*  (not perfect pitch!) one solution - accompanist changes to match!